# Shell prompt from initrd

Tags: opensuse, initrd

I have a problem with a Linux system that won't boot. The bootloader happily loads the kernel and initrd, but then the initrd script whines and complains and moans that it can't find the root device.

How to I **force** the initrd script to *give me a shell prompt* so I can actually *investigate* what's going on?

I tried unpacking initrd and making the `/init` shell script launch `bash -i`. But that didn't work at all; I see the Bash prompt appear, but the keyboard doesn't work. (Bash complains something about "cannot set progress group" and "inappropriate ioctl for device".)

In case it matters: OpenSUSE 13.1, which uses the old `mkinitrd` system. (Apparently newer versions use Dracut.) From what I can tell, `/init` is a small script that executes everything in `/boot` (a series of numbered Bash scripts).

- There's a script named `/boot/91-shell.sh`, which contains a comment which suggests that passing `shell=1` on the kernel command line will give me a shell prompt; it does not.
- There's also a comment in `/boot-02-start.sh` which claims that passing `linuxrc=trace` will give me debug output. It does, but it's useless; all I see is the endless device polling loop at the end of the script scrolling past, obliterating all previous output.

I really, really need to get *in* there and *see* what's actually happening with my own eyes to know where the problem is. (To be fair, I *am* trying to make the system boot in a slightly strange way, so problems are not unexpected here.)

Comment: I am not an OpenSUSE user but if I get a problem like this I will to add `init=/bin/bash` (or /usr/bin/bash) to my kernel parameters from the bootloader. It should open a bash shell with a root access

Comment: @HamzaAbbad That's a great suggestion. Unfortunately, I get exactly the same behavior (i.e., I can see the Bash prompt, but cannot type anything.)

Comment: @HamzaAbbad I take it back! If I try it *on a different computer*, it works perfectly. It's only the machine I actually need to use where it doesn't work. So maybe initrd is missing a keyboard driver or something?

Comment: Yes maybe the issue is with the keyboard driver. I am an Arch user, I don't know about how openSUSE booting work, but in Arch, one must put `base` as the first hook in the `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf` file, otherwise keyboard will not work in emergecy shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an Apple-specific issue. If I boot just about any Linux system on the MacBook Air I have to play with, the keyboard refuses to function. On any PC-based system, this works perfectly. So nothing to do with Linux not starting the right init binary; it's some kind of hardware driver issue.